# Admin Access control not working

Tags: php, controls, admin

i'm trying to check if a user is logged in or not then i wan't to check if he is an admin or not if not then redirect it to login page but it ain't working

```
// Access control
        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in') ) {
            if(!$this->session->userdata('user_rol') == 'Administrator'){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg','Please login as an admin first!');

            redirect('admin/login');
            }
        }
```

Any help please ??

Comment: Great, first of all what is not working?

Comment: it checks only if the user is logged in or not if logged in then redirects to dashboard without checking if it's an admin or not

Comment: `if(!$this->session->userdata('user_rol') == 'Administrator'){` shouldn't be that without `!`?

Comment: no it shouldn't be because it should redirect if it does not match the administrator string

Comment: @user2544859 Then you're doing it wrong. It's either `!($this->session->userdata('user_rol') == 'Administrator')` or `$this->session->userdata('user_rol') != 'Administrator'`. The latter one is obviously the form you should use.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois it's the second one thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your script does something different. The logic is if not logged in, it checks if the user rolle isn't admin.

I believe it should look like this, to do what you try to achieve.

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in') OR $this->session->userdata('user_rol') != 'Administrator') {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg','Please login as an admin first!');
    redirect('admin/login');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bundle dude i just realized my mistake ...
`!` sign should have been with the `=` sign and not before the `$this->session->userdata('user_rol')`  expression